# ASP.NET MVC Canvas App using Facebook C# SDK

Tags: facebook-c#-sdk

I have downloaded Prabir's application ASP.NET MVC Canvas App using Facebook C# SDK
showing the asp.net mvc and facebook integration.

I have tried logging in from the home page following the Click here to login link.

I can see that the clinet_id in the link is empty so the login does not work.

How do we set the client id , i.e. how do I run the application so that the client_id is assigned a valid id?

Ismar

Comment: I have found out how to set the application details in RegisterFacebookServices method of the NinjectMVC3 class. Now, the client_id is assigned the application id in the login link , but I still get the error page :-(

Comment: aded namespace bit to my application but now get 

This content cannot be displayed in a frame




To help protect the security of information you enter into this website, the publisher of this content does not allow it to be displayed in a frame.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

all working fine now - even managed to modify the code to support hosting multiple facebook applications in one asp.net mvc app

The last error was due to the way I had my mvc app sturcutred and had nothing to do with Parabir's authentication code.